# Angular 5 httpClient get Request vscode json error

Tags: json, angular, visual-studio-code, httpclient

My code is working perfectly, I just have a problem where my data from the get request is underlined in red and I don't understand how to fix this. The alert works perfectly. It alerts the SessionID that I need. I would just like to know how I can remove this underlined error, or maybe I am not doing the get request correctly? Thank you for any help :)

[image]
[image]

Comment: show also the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red wiggly lines that show up are indicating the type error. This indicates that it cannot determine the `utLogon_response` in type definition of `myData` variable. This can be solved by either of following ways:

1. Make `myData` as type `any` (**simple, quick and easier**)

   this.httpClient.get('hidden')
   .subscribe((myData: any) => {
       alert(myData.utLogon_response.sessionId);
   })

However, my understanding is that one should use any only in extreme conditioms since this is more like defeating the very purpose of Typescript.

2. Define proper type for `myData` and use it (**simple, slight coding but most appropriate**)

   interface IHiddenData {
     utLogon_response: any {
       sessionId: string;
     }
   }

   this.httpClient.get('hidden')
   .subscribe((myData: IHiddenData) => {
     alert(myData.utLogon_response.sessionId);
   })

I hope this helps!

NOTE: Somehow, this code is not getting properly formatted by the editor and I do know how to set it right.

Comment: Thank you for your in depth answer! :)

Answer (score 2):

try below code :

```
this.httpClient.get('hidden').subscribe((myData:any)=>{
    alert(myData.utLogon_responce.sessionId)
})
```

add **: any**

thanks,

Comment: Thanks, does the job perfectly :) @Abhi just has a more in depth answer